# Present a VC as full screen from a VC whose modalPresentationStyle is automatic

Tags: ios, navigation, swift5

Im trying to present a new view controller with modalPresentationStyle as .fullscreen from a view controller whose modalPresentationStyle is .automatic.

I added the modalPresentationStyle for the new VC as .fullscreen.But its coming as matching to the old VC only. How can I achieve the same. Im using swift 5.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
```

use `.overFullScreen` instead of `.fullScreen`